# device tree ERROR: Unable to parse input tree (syntax error)

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

I'm correctly generating my image Yocto-**hardknott-technexion** with this:

```
$ mkdir tn-imx-yocto
$ cd tn-imx-yocto
$ repo init -u https://github.com/TechNexion/tn-imx-yocto-manifest.git -b hardknott_5.10.y-next -m imx-5.10.52-2.1.0.xml
$ repo sync -j8
$ DISTRO=fsl-imx-x11 MACHINE=pico-imx7 BASEBOARD=pi source tn-setup-release.sh -b build-x11-pico-imx7
$ bitbake core-image-base
```

Then, I go to .../tn-imx-yocto/sources/meta-tn-imx-bsp/conf/machine/nano **pico-imx7.conf** And enable the **imx7d-pico-pi-m4.dtb** (**KERNEL_DEVICETREE_append = " imx7d-pico-pi-m4.dtb"**). Because I stay trying RPMsg with FreeRTOS in m4

**pico-imx7.conf**

```
#@TYPE: Machine
#@NAME: pico-imx7
#@SOC: i.MX7/Solo/Dual/UtraLowPower
#@DESCRIPTION: Machine configuration for PICO-IMX7 with QCA(Qualcomm)/BRCM(Broadcom) WLAN module
#@MAINTAINER: Po Cheng <po.cheng@technexion.com>

MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "mx7:mx7d:"
MACHINEOVERRIDES_EXTENDER_pico-imx7 = "uenv"

include conf/machine/include/imx-base.inc
include conf/machine/include/tune-cortexa7.inc
require conf/machine/tn-base.inc

#
# Kernel Device Trees
#
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ?= "linux-tn-imx"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel_mx7 = "linux-tn-imx"

KERNEL_DEVICETREE = "imx7d-pico-pi-qca.dtb" 
#                         imx7d-pico-pi-m4.dtb \
#"
KERNEL_DEVICETREE_append = " imx7d-pico-pi-m4.dtb"
#                    imx7d-pico-pi.dtb \
#                     imx7d-pico-pi-c2-qca.dtb imx7d-pico-pi-c2.dtb \
#                     imx7d-pico-nymph-qca.dtb imx7d-pico-nymph.dtb \
#                     imx7d-pico-dwarf-qca.dtb imx7d-pico-dwarf.dtb \
#                     imx7d-pico-hobbit-qca.dtb imx7d-pico-hobbit.dtb \
#"

# Setup the additional devicetree file
#KERNEL_DEVICETREE_append_voicehat = " imx7d-pico-pi-qca-voicehat.dtb \
#                                      imx7d-pico-pi-voicehat.dtb \
#                                      imx7d-pico-pi-c2-qca-voicehat.dtb \
#                                      imx7d-pico-pi-c2-voicehat.dtb "

# Bootloader Specifics
UBOOT_MACHINE = "pico-imx7d_spl_defconfig"

#M4_MACHINE = "pico-imx7d-pi"
#IMAGE_BOOTFILES_DEPENDS += "imx-m4-demos-tn:do_deploy"
#IMAGE_BOOTFILES += "hello_world.bin rpmsg_lite_pingpong_rtos_linux_remote.bin rpmsg_lite_str_echo_rtos_imxcm4.bin"
```

And (after that)  I get the issue: **Unable to parse input tree (syntax error)**
in file **baseboard_pico_pi.dtsi** line 52
(photo below)
I don't see anything wrong with **line 52** of the baseboard_pico_pi.dtsi file: **PICO_PI_GPIO_DEFS();**

**imx7d-pico-qca.dtsi about PICO_PI_GPIO_DEFS()**

```
#define PICO_NYMPH_GPIO_DEFS()  \
&gpio2 {                                                    \
    gpio-line-names =                                           \
        "", "", "GPIO_P28", "GPIO_P30", "GPIO_P32", "GPIO_P34", "", "",                 \
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",                                 \
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",                                 \
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "";                                 \
                                                        \
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_gpio2>;                                       \
}

#define PICO_PI_GPIO_DEFS() \
&gpio2 {                                                    \
    gpio-line-names =                                           \
        "GPIO_P24", "GPIO_P26", "GPIO_P28", "GPIO_P30", "", "GPIO_P34", "", "GPIO_P48",         \
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",                                 \
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",                                 \
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "";                                 \
                                                        \
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_gpio2>;                                       \
}
```

**baseboard_pico_pi.dtsi**

```
clocks {
        codec_osc: aud_mclk {
            compatible = "fixed-clock";
            #clock-cells = <0>;
            clock-frequency = <24576000>;
        };
    };
};

PICO_PI_GPIO_DEFS(); // line 52

&PICO_I2CA {
    status = "okay";

    codec: sgtl5000@a {
        compatible = "fsl,sgtl5000";
        reg = <0x0a>;
        clocks = <&codec_osc>;
        VDDA-supply = <&reg_2p5v>;
```

All device tree files referring to this issue are at this link:
https://github.com/neuberfran/technexion2

How can I solve this? (pls)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is requirement of Stack Overflow for an error message and a code to be in the **question post** as **text**. *Links* and *images* are NOT sufficient to fulfil that requirement. Please, edit the question post and add into it textual representation of **exact error message** and textual content of the file that message refers to. See also [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev This is not nice of you. The error is explicit in the topic, in the description and in the first photo. That way you mess up my issue.

Comment: You could read the post on our "meta" site about using images for code and error messages: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question. Also there is a post about why exact error message is important: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Comment: @Tsyvarev What did you not understand? Do you have knowledge about device -tree? It becomes impossible

Comment: The device tree should be in the question post as **text**, not as an *image* and not as a *link* to the repo.

Comment: What is `PICO_PI_GPIO_DEFS();` supposed to be? It doesn't look like device tree syntax.

Comment: Assuming `PICO_PI_GPIO_DEFS();` is supposed to be expanding a CPP macro, you need to at least show its definition. I assume it is defined by `#include "tnmacro.h"` in your **baseboard_pico_pi.dtsi** file, but I cannot see **tnmacro.h** in your git repository.

Comment: If I were to guess the cause of the error, I would guess that the `PICO_PI_GPIO_DEFS()` macro expansion already ends with a semicolon and that the parser is complaining about the additional semicolon on the line `PICO_PI_GPIO_DEFS();`.

Comment: @Ian Abbott
 I just now saw your comment and I'm providing an answer.

Comment: @Ian Abbott I edited this question and it also includes: imx7d-pico-qca.dtsi about PICO_PI_GPIO_DEFS(). I imagine I have solved this issue here by replacing imx7d-pico-pi-m4.dtb with imx7d-pico-pi-qca-m4.dtb. I'm still having this difficult issue to get RPMsg:
https://github.com/TechNexion/freertos-tn/issues/8  Possibly I will have to create another topic here or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change imx7d-pico-pi-m4.dtb to imx7d-pico-pi-qca-m4.dtb in the Yocto/Hardknott/technexion configuration file called pico-imx7.conf(described in the post)